# Who is the guy in the men’s wash room who got killed accidentally?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

In *Mission: Impossible - Fallout*, Ethan Hunt and August Walker tracked a guy in men’s wash room who got killed accidentally. He is not Lark, then who is this guy and how did he get the invitation band?

Comment: Didn't Henry Cavil hire him as a decoy, and then blame Ethan for doing that exact same thing?

Comment: He could be a normal guy who had the invitation the way all other people got the invitation and happens to be in the bathrom at the moment

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by eduffy in [comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95944/who-is-the-guy-in-the-men-s-wash-room-who-got-killed-accidentally#comment162271_95944), this character is decoy Lark. [Medium.com](https://medium.com/@quartet4/the-asian-decoy-who-stole-mission-impossible-fallout-f35fa668736d) 
also, have nice details about the character and also provide the information that he is played by stunt actor [Liang Yang](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2403982/) .